# are play 2.1.x modules compatible with 2.2.x , link refers to 2.1.x modules

Tags: playframework

i see the modules list mentioned for 2.2 @http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Modules

but the modules are referring to 2.1.X .

Are these module compatible with 2.2.X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they need to be build with play 2.2.

But most of them are on github, you can fork them and adapt the code to work with play 2.2 according to Migration instructions.